# How To Rewrite Wordpress URL to remove ? parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following URL in a wordpress website:

```
https://www.example.com/previews/mundoflamenco/gitarre/?gname=myname
```

I would like it to be rewritten like so (so the ?gname= should be hidden):

```
https://www.example.com/previews/mundoflamenco/gitarre/myname
```

I have tried it using .htaccess like so but it unfortunately doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /gitarre\?gname=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ gitarre/%1? [R=302,L]
```

Some more information:

just if anyone faces the same issue as I had after I managed to get the redirect working: Wordpress didn't find the page anymore after this (404):

You need to add the following in htaccess to tell wordpress to exclude this folder:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add the following after this line

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(gitarre|gitarre/.*)$ 

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.*/gitarre/?)\?gname=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# remaining rules below this line
```